# Is there a function in MySQL that removes a polygon that intersects with another polygon

Tags: mysql, polygon, spatial

I have county and city polygons and I'm trying to create in MySQL to give me the county minus the city polygons so I can show the unincorporated portion of the county.

I'm able to overlay the cities onto the county with the ST_Intersection but I want the reverse.

```
SELECT
   ST_Intersection(part_1.shape, part_2.shape), part_2.name
FROM (SELECT * FROM us_county  where county = 326) AS part_1,
           cities as part_2
WHERE ST_Intersects(part_1.shape, part_2.shape)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`ST_Difference` should do what you want:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-difference

Comment: That doesn't work well with multiple records (city within a county) from the cities table.